# Substring a column of data in Excel

Tags: excel, rename

I have had a lot of files processed through some custom software which has exported the data into Excel. The data is spread across a number of columns but the key identifier is the file name (see below):

```
Column A                                          B      C
E:\FT XML TO CONVERT\2007\FTDA-2007-1231.txt    980034  3919
E:\FT XML TO CONVERT\2007\FTDA-2007-1229.txt    1777836 7404
E:\FT XML TO CONVERT\2007\FTDA-2007-1228.txt    1164391 3732
E:\FT XML TO CONVERT\2007\FTDA-2007-1227.txt    1075451 3548
E:\FT XML TO CONVERT\2007\FTDA-2007-1224.txt    941111  3635
E:\FT XML TO CONVERT\2007\FTDA-2007-1222.txt    2089585 9619
```

However, I need to align the data in column B and C with a list of dates in another worksheet. I think the first step would be to change the column A to represent a date rather than a file name/location. I would be extremely grateful if someone could suggest how to rename Column A into being dates such as:

```
31/12/2007
29/12/2007
28/12/2007


etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in column D:

```
   =LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),".txt",""),9),7) & "-" & RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),".txt",""),2)
```

Then format column D with a date format.

Comment: Thanks Doug. That has worked and renamed everything in this format:

2007-12-31
2007-12-28
2007-12-27

If I want to align the data relevant to each date in one worksheet with a series of dates in another, do you have a suggested solution for that?

The issue is one worksheet has information for the Mon - Fri, while the other has Mon - Sat. However removing every 6th row each time won't work as occasionally dates are missed. All a bit disjointed data unfortunately.

Comment: There's lots of questions on SO about looking up data from one sheet to another. Generally, you use the `VLOOKUP` function. To delete the Saturdays, use the `WEEKDAY` function, filter to the number equivalent to Saturday and delete those rows, or just format the dates with one that includes the day. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the =MID() function to extract three substrings from the filename column.